# Redirecionar usuário encerrando a sessão php com Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando encerrar uma `sessão` `php` e redirecionar um usuário após troca de senha para forçar novo `login` no retorno de uma ação, o redirecionamento está ocorrendo mas não sei exatamente como encerrar a sessão nesse momento.

O que tenho no retorno da alteração da senha é isso:

```
if (response.codigo == "1") {
    $("#msgResultadoSenha").html('×AVISO!' + response.mensagem + '');

    // Atualizando os dados do formulário
    window.location.href = "index.php#ajax/iPerfil.php";

} else {
    $("#msgResultadoSenha").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + response.mensagem + '');
}
```

Comment: Uma sessão em especifico ou todas criadas? `session_destroy()` elimina todas as sessões daquele usuário. `$_SESSION['nom_ses'] = ''` faz com que a sessão receba vazio e assim "eliminada". Como você está planejando fazer?

Comment: Olá @Everson, como disse na pergunta, a sessão que quero encerrar é a  do processo que valida o usuário, como estou planejando fazer é Jquery + php.

Comment: Sim, mas é que por exemplo, você trocou a senha do usuário no PHP e retornou ao JS, mas já poderia destruir as sessões após trocar a senha e depois só redirecionar. Só uma ideia, caso não seja a forma que você precisa, vamos esperar outros usuários mostrarem outras soluções.

Comment: Ótima ideia @Everson, estava travado nessa questão, já me deu uma grande direção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguindo a dica do Everson, fiz da seguinte forma, no php ficou assim, após a alteração da senha:

```
    // DESTRUINDO A SESSÃO
    session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
    session_regenerate_id(true);
```

No retorno:

```
if (response.codigo == "1") {
    $("#msgResultadoSenha").html('×AVISO!' + response.mensagem + '');

    setTimeout(function(){location.href="login.php"} , 5000);   

} else {
    $("#msgResultadoSenha").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + response.mensagem + '');
                            }
```